# Add meta box to admin users table

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a few meta boxes to the admin users table but am unable to find anything that tells me how to do so. I have the code below which I expected to work, but it's not outputting anything.

```
    function status_meta_box_markup() {

}

function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'status-meta-box',
        'Status',
        'status_meta_box_markup',
        'user',
        'normal',
        'high',
        null
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');
```

even with the markup function blank, we should still get the meta box title appearing but I have nothing. any idea's?

Comment: I have found a solution, not sure if it is possible to actually add meta boxes to the users pages, every bit of documentation I found said that I could only use meta boxes with post types. I have seen the Advanced Custom Fields have managed it somehow, so if anyone knows how they did it please comment. However I managed to add meta fields / data to the users pages using the code below

Comment: `add_action('edit_user_profile', 'custom_function');`
`add_action('show_user_profile', 'custom_function');`
`add_action('personal_options_update', 'custom_update_function');`
`add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'custom_update_function');`